# A memory leak in php5.6.19

Tags: php, arrays, memory-leaks

Who can explain the behaviour of 5.6.19.
Is the following code:

```
<?php
function convert($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}

function example()
{
    $a = [];
    $k = 0;
    while($k <= 100000)
    {
        $a[$k] =  mt_rand();
        //$a[$k] =  trim(mt_rand());
        $k++;
        //unset($a);
    }
    //mt_rand();
    //trim('');
    //$mem = memory_get_usage(true);
    //echo $mem.' '.convert($mem).PHP_EOL;
    unset($a);
    trim('');
    $mem = memory_get_usage(true);
    echo $mem.' '.convert($mem).PHP_EOL;
}

example();
example();
example();
example();
example();
echo PHP_EOL;
$mem = memory_get_usage(true);
echo $mem.' '.convert($mem);
```

It is 5 times we call the function "example". It generates an array of 100,000 elements.
After generating the array, and before "unset", we call trim.
Memory Performance:

```
786432 768 kb
786432 768 kb
1048576 1 mb
1310720 1.25 mb
1572864 1.5 mb

1572864 1.5 mb
```

After generating the array, and before "unset", we call mt_rand.
Memory Performance:

```
786432 768 kb
1048576 1 mb
1310720 1.25 mb
1310720 1.25 mb
1310720 1.25 mb

1048576 1 mb
```

After generating the array, and before "unset", we call "mt_rand", and wrap the array value of the "mt_rand" in "trim".
Memory Performance:

```
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb

524288 512 kb
```

After generating the array, and before "unset", we call memory_get_usage.
Memory Performance:

```
786432 768 kb
1048576 1 mb
1310720 1.25 mb
1572864 1.5 mb
1572864 1.5 mb

1572864 1.5 mb
```

After generating the array, and before "unset", we do not call anything.
Memory Performance:

```
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb

524288 512 kb
```

The code runs on:

```
$ php5 -v
PHP 5.6.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with blackfire v1.10.0, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfireio Inc.
```

**P.S**

When you add a cast (string) for the value of the array, we get:

```
1310720 1.25 mb
1310720 1.25 mb
1572864 1.5 mb
1835008 1.75 mb
1835008 1.75 mb

1835008 1.75 mb
```

Example Code:

```
<?php
function convert($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}

function example()
{
    $a = [];
    $k = 0;
    while($k <= 100000)
    {
        $a[$k] =  (string)mt_rand();
        $k++;
    }
    unset($a);
    $mem = memory_get_usage(true);
    echo $mem.' '.convert($mem).PHP_EOL;
}

example();
example();
example();
example();
example();
echo PHP_EOL;
$mem = memory_get_usage(true);
echo $mem.' '.convert($mem);

while(true)
{
    sleep(10);
}
```

When you add a cast (int) to the value of the array, we get:

```
786432 768 kb
1048576 1 mb
1310720 1.25 mb
1572864 1.5 mb
1572864 1.5 mb

1572864 1.5 mb
```

Example Code:

```
<?php
function convert($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}

function example()
{
    $a = [];
    $k = 0;
    while($k <= 100000)
    {
        $a[$k] =  (int)mt_rand();
        $k++;
    }
    unset($a);
    $mem = memory_get_usage(true);
    echo $mem.' '.convert($mem).PHP_EOL;
}

example();
example();
example();
example();
example();
echo PHP_EOL;
$mem = memory_get_usage(true);
echo $mem.' '.convert($mem);

while(true)
{
    sleep(10);
}
```

**P.S.S**

As for me, this is due to the variables and their types.
Another example:

```
<?php
function convert($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}

function example()
{
    $a = [];
    for($k = 0; $k<=100000; $k++)
    {
        $b = mt_rand();
        $a[$k] = (string)$b;
        //unset($b);
    }
    unset($a);
    $mem = memory_get_usage(true);
    echo $mem.' '.convert($mem).PHP_EOL;
}

for($a = 0; $a<=5; $a++)
{
    example();
}

echo PHP_EOL;
$mem = memory_get_usage(true);
echo $mem.' '.convert($mem);

while(true)
{
    sleep(10);
}
```

Performance:

```
1310720 1.25 mb
1835008 1.75 mb
1572864 1.5 mb
1835008 1.75 mb
1835008 1.75 mb
2097152 2 mb

1835008 1.75 mb (If the code is run more than ~200 times - the maximum memory usage 12.75MB)
```

But if I remove the variable "$b"

```
<?php
function convert($size)
{
    $unit=array('b','kb','mb','gb','tb','pb');
    return @round($size/pow(1024,($i=floor(log($size,1024)))),2).' '.$unit[$i];
}

function example()
{
    $a = [];
    for($k = 0; $k<=100000; $k++)
    {
        $b = mt_rand();
        $a[$k] = (string)$b;
        unset($b);
    }
    unset($a);
    $mem = memory_get_usage(true);
    echo $mem.' '.convert($mem).PHP_EOL;
}

for($a = 0; $a<=5; $a++)
{
    example();
}

echo PHP_EOL;
$mem = memory_get_usage(true);
echo $mem.' '.convert($mem);

while(true)
{
    sleep(10);
}
```

Result:

```
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb
524288 512 kb

524288 512 kb
```

**P.S.S.S**

***In the php7 - everything is working properly.***

Comment: I don't think you can reliably detect memory leaks like this. For one, memory_get_usage(true) returns allocated memory, which may be more than is actually in use, ie which hasn't been released to the OS yet. Also unset doesn't guarantee the object's memory will be released right away, since this is governed by the garbage collector. Even if there are no references, the collection may not kick in right away, see http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php  That totally unrelated function calls like your trim('') influence the results seems to confirm the measurement is off.

Comment: You are right, but still strange. Last exeperimental slightly rewritten so that he repeated all the time (and added gc_collect_cycles ();), with an interval of 10 seconds, and repeated, but already looked at the evidence htop.
RES - when I did not delete the variable stopped at ~ 30580.
Repeated experimentation with the removal of a variable: ~ 20752
Although this big difference, compared to the figures, which are given out memory_get_usage (true);